# Firebase : Cannot see AVG and SUM values for Events

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

Here's what I send (post_score)

```
public void AnalyticsPostScore(String arg0, String arg1, String arg2) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    long scoreVal = Long.parseLong(arg0);
    long levelVal = Long.parseLong(arg1);
    bundle.putLong("score", scoreVal);
    bundle.putLong("level", levelVal);
    bundle.putString("character",arg2);
    mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("post_score", bundle);
}
```

I send score data to Firebase analytics. I can see the passing data in StreamView tab, and I can see the values passing "Level - 1 and Score - 25" etc. But when I check these in "Events" tab, I cannot see AVG and SUM values, only 0. (I sent the same data a week ago, still cannot see them on the panel). Am I doing something wrong ?

*Note : I pass the values as string to the function due to Game Maker Studio's extension system's condition that I can only pass string/double.*

Answer (score 0):

You can send it like below

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("character",8);
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("post_score", bundle);
```

It will reflect in Firebase after a day.